# Payment Pending Nofication Diplay before Last 5 Days Php mysqli

Tags: php, ajax

Payment notification automatically display before last 5 days.what i tried so far i attached below. no errors there but check whether is this code is correct the way i wrote. example if i select the date 18.12.2018 when save the record. after that before last 5 days in this date 18.12.2018 . notification should display. like this payment pending.

```
<?php
include("../php/db.php");
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET') {
    $sql = "select id,date,total,pay,due,pay_date,payment_type from sales ";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
        {
            $id =  $row["id"];
            $paydate =  $row["pay_date"];
            $duedate = date("Y-m-d", mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m"), date("d") + 7));

            if ($duedate >= $paydate) 
            {
                echo  "</br>" .$id.  "  " . "Pending payment" . " "  . $paydate;
            }
        }

    }
}
?>
```

Comment: You tagged as "ajax" but no code for that, and didn't tag as "mysql/mysqli" or date-related. The question is unclear.

Comment: You're trying to parse a date from MySQL and then determining if the current date is within 5 days of that date?

Comment: can you write the code sir it is more helpful for me thanks

Comment: Can you confirm/clarify/explain specifically what it is you're trying to do?  It's hard to tell from your question.

Comment: what are payments due it will show. if i select the date 18.12.2018 when save the record. after that before last 5 days in this date 18.12.2018 . notification should display. like this payment pending.now i hope understood my question

Comment: Yes, I read your question.  Copying/pasting it here doesn't add any useful information.  Your question isn't clear... what I think you mean is what I suggested above... that you're trying to parse a data from your MySQL result, then compare that date to `now()` to see if it's within 5 days.  If that's what your question is, please confirm.  If it's different, please explain.

Comment: yes. sir i cofirm you got my question date to now() to see if it's within 5 days. how to write in mysql